# Passing an Array of an Array to a subroutine using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, subroutine, addressing

Ok, so I got an array of an array (AoA) and I need to pass it to a subroutine, and then access it. This works… but is it strictly correct and indeed is there a better way that I should be doing this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$a = "deep";
push(@b,$a);
push(@c,\@b);

print "c = @{$c[0]}\n";
&test(\@c);

sub test
{
    $d = $_[0];
    print "sub c = @{$$d[0]}\n";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `$d = $_[0]` I'd say `my ($d) = @_`.   And in your `sub`, you should be able to say `$d->[0]->[0]` to dereference your AoA.

Answer (score 3):

The definitely better way to do it is to `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and to declare your variables before using them.

Also, you know that is not good practice to name your vars `a` or `b` - give them meaningful names, especially because the `$a` variable for example, is defined by the compiler (the one used with `sort {} @`).

Comment: Using meaningful names is always helpful, of course, but the `$a` variable is only predefined in the dynamic scope of a `sort` call. Defining global `$a` and `$b` variables poses no conflict with `sort`.

Comment: @qwrrty try this `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; $a=1; print $a;'` and then try this `perl -e 'use strict; use warnings; $r=1; print $r;'`

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;          # Always!
use warnings;        # Always!

sub test {
    my ($d) = @_;
    print "$d->[0][0]\n";

    # Or to print all the deep elements.
    for my $d2 (@$d) {
       for (@$d2) {
          print "$_\n";
       }
    }
}

{
   my $a = "deep";   # or:  my @c = [ [ "deep" ] ];
   my @b;
   my @c;
   push(@b,$a);
   push(@c,\@b);
   test(\@c);        # Can't pass arrays per say, just refs. You had this right.
}
```

Still needs better names. In particular, `$a` and `$b` should be avoided as they can interfere with `sort`.